# regexp: reversing similar elements in a string

Tags: regex

I am using my texteditor (e-texteditor)'s regular expression to try to reverse some elements in a line of code. So here's what I have:

```
  [[Date.today, "Today (#{Date.today})"], [Date.tomorrow, "Tomorrow (#{Date.tomorrow})"], [Date.today+3, "In 3 Days (#{Date.today+3})"], [this_weekend, "This Weekend (#{this_weekend})"]]
```

And I actually wanted it the reverse of it:

```
  [[this_weekend, "This Weekend (#{this_weekend})"], [Date.today+3, "In 3 Days (#{Date.today+3})"], [Date.tomorrow, "Tomorrow (#{Date.tomorrow})"], [Date.today, "Today (#{Date.today})"]]
```

By the way, the code is in Ruby in case you're wondering. To visualize better:

Have: [A, B, C, D]
Want: [D, C, B, A]

So far, I am doing the dumb thing (or at least I think so) by searching for

```
 (\[[^[].+?\]),\s(\[[^[].+?\]),\s(\[[^[].+?\]),\s(\[[^[].+?\])
```

so it's like search for (A),\s(B),\s(C),\s(D)

And then replace it with

```
  $4, $3, $2, $1
```

While that works, but it's not very nice isn't it, what if I have more than 4 elements. That's a lot of typing up still. How will you approach it?

Here is the regex 'engine/syntax' that e-texteditor supports
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: are you sticking to your e-texteditor or also accept other way? e.g. awk, sed, vim...?

Comment: No, I am open to learning from other texteditor, esp. vim. 'But I think e-texteditor comes with a pretty 'standard' regex syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `(\[[^[].+?\]),` could be a problamatic subexpression.
It works in this case because the sample data you provide is
well formed. In ill-formed context, it could overflow to the next `],`
if not preceded by a `[`, even though `.+?` is non greedy.

It might be better as this `(\[[^\[\]]+\])`.

To your question, I think that only .NET has variable amount of
capture buffers (its Capture Collection) and even then I'm not sure
how its variability could be used on the replacement side.
Example:  `\[(?:(\[[^\[\]]+\])(?:,\s*|(?=\])))+\]` should make
a variable collection that you may be able to programatically
reverse on the replacement side. I've never done this so not
too sure.

Otherwise, it involves a couple of seperate intermediate steps
outside of a regex.

In Perl, it'd be like use global search and replace, where the
replacement side is a callback function that gets passed each individual record.

s/`(\[(?:\[[^\[\]]+\](?:,\s*|(?=\])))+\])`/ func($1) /eg;`

Then in the callback, parse the individual elements from the record passed, then
rebuild the string in reverse order, which then gets passed back to the original
regex to be used as the replacement for that record.

Perl code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $samp = '[[Date.today, "Today (#{Date.today})"], [Date.tomorrow, "Tomorrow (#{Date.tomorrow})"], [Date.today+3, "In 3 Days (#{Date.today+3})"], [this_weekend, "This Weekend (#{this_weekend})"]]';

$samp =~ s/(\[(?:\[[^\[\]]+\](?:,\s*|(?=\])))+\])/ func($1) /eg;

print "\n$samp\n";


sub func
{
   my $rec = shift;
   my @elements = $rec =~ /(\[[^\[\]]+\])/g;
   return '['. join( ', ', reverse @elements ) . ']';
}
```

Output:

```
[[this_weekend, "This Weekend (#{this_weekend})"], [Date.today+3, "In 3 Days (#{Date.today+3})"], [Date.tomorrow, "Tomorrow (#{Date.tomorrow})"], [Date.today, "Today (#{Date.today})"]]
```

Comment: -@sln  Hi, thanks for writing such detailed explanation. I am definitely changing the subexpression as you suggest. But I was hoping to be able to do all the regexing within the texteditor. Otherwise, Ruby will actually do a very decent job in like 3 lines.

Comment: @Nik - As far as I know, the Regular Expression part of any application (lang, editors, etc...) is via an import library. PCRE is the primary flavor. Some have extended the capabilities, built upon it (primarily .NET). Textmate looks like it uses standard PCRE. That means you will not be able to reference a variable amount of capture buffers as PCRE doesen't allow it. So this is at least a three step process: 1 - capture the record, 2 - parse the elements, 3 - replace the reordered record. That this can't be done in a 1-step PCRE regex is well known. Good luck~

Comment: I see. that makes sense. I mean, writing a regex engine each time you wanted to write a texteditor does sound excessive. I guess what awk is not too far away from what I envisioned..Thanks for all the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

well i post an awk oneliner to solve your problem. if you have to stick to your editor, just forget it.

```
awk -F'\\[\\[|\\]\\]|\\], *\\[' '{for (i=NF;i>=1;i--) {s=s&&$i?s",":s;s=($i)?s"["$i"]":s"";} s="["s"]";print s}'    yourFile
```

**testing:**

```
this is the string we want to test:

kent$  echo {1..10}|sed -r 's/([0-9]+)/[\1],/g;s/^/[/;s/,$/]/'  

[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10]]
```

now push it to my awk script:

```
kent$  echo {1..10}|sed -r 's/([0-9]+)/[\1],/g;s/^/[/;s/,$/]/'|awk -F'\\[\\[|\\]\\]|\\], *\\[' '{for (i=NF;i>=1;i--) {s=s&&$i?s",":s;s=($i)?s"["$i"]":s"";} s="["s"]";print s}'   

[[10],[9],[8],[7],[6],[5],[4],[3],[2],[1]]
```

with the given example from you:

```
kent$  echo '[[Date.today, "Today (#{Date.today})"], [Date.tomorrow, "Tomorrow (#{Date.tomorrow})"], [Date.today+3, "In 3 Days (#{Date.today+3})"], [this_weekend, "This Weekend (#{this_weekend})"]]'|awk -F'\\[\\[|\\]\\]|\\], *\\[' '{for (i=NF;i>=1;i--) {s=s&&$i?s",":s;s=($i)?s"["$i"]":s"";} s="["s"]";print s}'    

[[this_weekend, "This Weekend (#{this_weekend})"],[Date.today+3, "In 3 Days (#{Date.today+3})"],[Date.tomorrow, "Tomorrow (#{Date.tomorrow})"],[Date.today, "Today (#{Date.today})"]]
```

Comment: Hi Kent, thanks for the suggestion . This is my first time hearing of awk. But I was hoping to restrict my regexing within the texteditor.